# parallelization of events notification in case of file creation

Tags: file, parallel-processing, python-multithreading, inotify

I am using "Inotify" to logs event when a file or folder is created in a directory ( tmp here) . The example here does the job in as serial process. Meaning, All file creation are treated one after the other, in a sequential way.

```
import logging

import inotify.adapters

_DEFAULT_LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'

_LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def _configure_logging():
    _LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    ch = logging.StreamHandler()

    formatter = logging.Formatter(_DEFAULT_LOG_FORMAT)
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)

    _LOGGER.addHandler(ch)

def _main():
    i = inotify.adapters.Inotify()

    i.add_watch(b'/tmp')

    try:
        for event in i.event_gen():
            if event is not None:
                (header, type_names, watch_path, filename) = event
                _LOGGER.info("WD=(%d) MASK=(%d) COOKIE=(%d) LEN=(%d) MASK->NAMES=%s "
                             "WATCH-PATH=[%s] FILENAME=[%s]",
                             header.wd, header.mask, header.cookie, header.len, type_names,
                             watch_path.decode('utf-8'), filename.decode('utf-8'))
    finally:
        i.remove_watch(b'/tmp')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _configure_logging()
    _main()
```

I would like to introduce parallelization of the events notification in case of several files are uploaded by importing threading, should I add a threading as loop ? 
Second concern, I am not sure where it would make sens to put the thread function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The below scripts handles multiples events in case of multiples sessions. So in my case, this is enough. I Added the multiprocessing  option instead of threading. I found multiprocessing faster than threading.

```
 import logging
 import threading
 import inotify.adapters
 import multiprocessing  

 _DEFAULT_LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'

 _LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

 def _configure_logging():
     _LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

     ch = logging.StreamHandler()

     formatter = logging.Formatter(_DEFAULT_LOG_FORMAT)
     ch.setFormatter(formatter)

     _LOGGER.addHandler(ch)



 def PopUpMessage (event):
     if event is not None:
         (header, type_names, watch_path, filename) = event
         _LOGGER.info("WD=(%d) MASK=(%d) COOKIE=(%d) LEN=(%d) MASK->NAMES=%s "
             "WATCH-PATH=[%s] FILENAME=[%s]",
             header.wd, header.mask, header.cookie, header.len, type_names,
             watch_path.decode('utf-8'), filename.decode('utf-8'))


 def My_main(count):
     i = inotify.adapters.Inotify()
     DirWatcher=i.add_watch(b'/PARA')
     try:
         while True: 
             for event in i.event_gen():
                 m = multiprocessing.Process(target=PopUpMessage, args=(event,))
                 m.start()            

     finally:
         i.remove_watch(b'/PARA')

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     _configure_logging()
     N = multiprocessing.Process(target=My_main)
     N.start()
```